# Enabling Custom Identity Broker Access to the AWS Console with MFA

Tags: boto3, multi-factor-authentication, aws-sts

I would like to incorporate MFA into the Python Code following this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html

I have an IAM user that works great when I assume a role with MFA required through the CLI. Here is my configuration.

.aws/config

```
source_profile = developer_v2
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/developer-role-v2
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::123456789:mfa/developer
```

.aws/config

```
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXX
```

Finally my trust policy for the IAM Role

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalType": "User"
        },
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I remove MFA, I receive a URL but when I have MFA included it throws an exception json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I have tried to add an additional line for url_credentials but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: You are missing `{` in your policy. But maybe its due to copy-and-paste to SO?

Answer (score 0):

The change ended up being quite simple. Here is where the change happened:

`mfa_TOTP = input("Enter the MFA code: ")`

```
assumed_role_object = sts_connection.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/developer-role-v2",
    RoleSessionName="Developer",
    DurationSeconds=3600,
    SerialNumber="arn:aws:iam::123456789:mfa/developer",
    TokenCode=mfa_TOTP
    )
```

It will ask me to enter my MFA code and will create a URL for me to assume the role.